# Distinction of a vector

Tags: vectors

I'm a programmer and not a mathematiction. However, I work with simple vectors and have a simple question. Unfortunately, I cannot find any helpful literature (mostly because I don't even know how to search for that).

Imagine the following vectors (just an example, the real dimension is >10000):

a={1,0,0,0,1} and b={0,0,1,1,0}

Is there any mathematic or statistical operation to say that these vectors are the "same", e.g. because they have three "0" and two "1"? I thought of simple multiplications or other simple operations (average of elements, sorting, etc.).

None of them really work for me. Does anyone have an idea?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Two vectors are the same only if they have the same components (same place with same value). This definition is independent from the basis.

Comment: What values can your elements take? If they're limited to 0 and 1, and you're trying to count the 1s, it's as simple as summing the elements, isn't it? But note that vector equality demands that every element in a certain position be identical for two vectors to be equal (i.e. same elements, same order).

Comment: @Deepak: I'm sorry the example was too simple. The vector can have any real number.

Comment: @Emilio: So it's simply not possible?

Comment: What are you looking for? You've already been informed of the criterion for vector equality. Both. must obviously have the same dimension. Now compare element at every position, the elements must all match for equality.

Comment: Yes. If the two lists of number are genuinely vectors ( i.e. the position of the components is important as their values), you mast compare any component of one vector with the same component of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you say vectors are equal if they contain the same elements (with multiplicity, but regardless of order).

Then define the operation $\mathrm{sort}(v)$ which spits out a vector $v$ sorted, e.g. increasing. Then two vectors $v$ and $w$ (of the same length $n$) contain the same elements (and are equal in your terms) if and only if $\mathrm{sort}(v)=\mathrm{sort}(w)$ componentwise, i.e. you define $\tilde v=\mathrm{sort}(v)$ and $\tilde w=\mathrm{sort}(w)$ and then you check all entries

$$\tilde v_i=\tilde w_i,\qquad\text{for all $i=1,...,n$}.$$

There is no standard notation for this (as far as I know), so you are free to 
define some relation, e.g.

$$v\equiv w\qquad:\Leftrightarrow\qquad\mathrm{sort}(v)=\mathrm{sort}(w)\;\text{ componentwise}.$$

Comment: I thought about a similar solution and then I thought comparing two vectors (i.e. to have a "degree" of samness) could be done by calculating a distance (e.g. Hemming distance). However, in this case I can only compare two vectors at the same time and the result is only valid for those to vectors. This makes it impractical for a huge matrix. That's why I hoped to find an independent way to define something like a "identity" or "vector signature" by applying a mathematical operation on that. I think that something like this just doesn't exist.

Comment: @Vetemi I am not sure what your final goal should look like! For example, you never mentioned that there are *many* such vectors, that you have to compare each one to each other one, that the method of comparison should meat some efficiency goals, etc. These are *important informations* that should be included in the question or every answer will miss the point! Are you maybe looking for some way to "hash" a vector to create an easier comparable value from it? A distance, as you wanted one, can be defined via $d(v,w)=\|\mathrm{sort}(v)-\mathrm{sort}(w)\|$ but might not me efficient enough.

Comment: @Vetemi For example, you can compute the sum of the vector entries (or any other order independent check sum) to compare two of your vectors efficiently. This will show if they are different, but maybe not if they are the same.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I haven't put all details to that because I wanted to simplify my question to the base problem. So, yes comparison is my ultimate goal but to achieve it in an efficient way I need a hash calculation. Summing, multiplying, calculate average, median or everything I had in mind will not give a distinct result, e.g.: vector c={1,1,1,1} and vector d={4,0,0,0} will give the same sum and are far away of being the "same" in the sense I need it. This also applies to all above operations. That's why I hoped that there is way of calculate a distinct value for "same" vectors.

Comment: @Vetemi A hash works by compressing much information into less by giving up injectivity. So collisions are unavoidable. One way to reduce the chance of collisions is to choose a larger "hash-space". Instead of just computing $s_1=v_1+\cdots+v_n$, you can additionally compute $s_2=v_1^2+\cdots +v_n^2$. Then a vectors identity is given by a set of two numbers, $s_1$ and $s_2$, therefore a much smaller chance for collisions. You can compute further such sums $s_k$ to avoid collisions. But as your vector space is $n$-dim., you will need $n$ such sums $s_1,...,s_n$ to avoid collisions completely.

Comment: @Vetemi Such a sequence $\vec s=(s_1,...,s_n)$ will give you the complete (order independent) identity of $v$, but computing it has a complexity of $\mathcal O(n^2)$. Useful sorting algorithms are of complexity $\mathcal O(n\log n)$, hence much better. In this sense, you can see $\mathrm{sort}(v)$ as some hash of your vector. If a small chance of collision is acceptable, then I recommend computing and comparing $s_1,...,s_k$, with a complexity of $\mathcal O(kn)$. You will not find a single number compressing the information of the whole vector,  just because of dimensionality.